# Rails 4: How to implement class table inheritance?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, class-table-inheritance

How do I properly implement CTI in Rails 4? I tried by using [dbview_cti](https://github.com/mvdamme/dbview_cti) but this gem creates a view with inherited attributes, not an inherited table. I would be grateful for an explanation and example. Most of the tutorials are based on STI.